# when i cal ajax my whole content is loaded in that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my script   code through which i send data to my controller on ajax cal all things are working fine but the problem is my whole content comes in that div i also want enable scrollbar to be at last while calling need good suggestions

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#my-form").on("submit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url:this.action,
                    type:this.method,
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my actual View code on which i apply chat app i also want that on ever 10ms my page refresh automatically  at reciever end message can be read as soon as possible

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <section class="panel">
        <header class="panel-heading">
            Chat <span class="tools pull-right">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
                @*<a href="~/Views/Chat/Create.cshtml">~/Views/Chat/Create.cshtml</a>*@
                <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
            </span>
        </header>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AllMessages","Chat",FormMethod.Post,new {id="my-form" }))
        {
            <div class="panel-body"  id="result">
                <div class="chat-conversation1" >
                    <div class="slimScrollDiv" >
                        <ul class="conversation-list" >
                            @for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                if (msg[i].sender_id == ViewBag.Reciever_id)
                                {
                                    <li class="clearfix">

                                        <div class="chat-avatar">
                                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ViewBag.RecieverImage))" alt="" height="50" width="40" class="img-rounded" />
                                            <i>@Html.Label(msg[i].datetime.ToString())</i>    @*time from db*@
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="conversation-text">
                                            <div class="ctext-wrap">
                                                <i> @ViewBag.RecieverName</i>
                                                <p>
                                                    @Html.Label(msg[i].messages)
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </li>
                                    }
                                    else if (msg[i].sender_id == ViewBag.SenderId)
                                    {

                                        <li class="clearfix odd" style="margin-left:10px;">
                                            <div class="chat-avatar">
                                                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ViewBag.SenderImage))" alt="" height="50" width="40"  class="img-rounded" />
                                                <i>@Html.Label(msg[i].datetime.ToString())</i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="conversation-text">
                                                <div class="ctext-wrap">
                                                    <i>  @ViewBag.SenderName</i>
                                                    <p>
                                                        @Html.Label(msg[i].messages)
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>



                        </div>
                        <div class="row chatSendBox">
                            <div class="col-xs-10 ">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.reciever_id, new { @Value= ViewBag.Reciever_id })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.datetime, new { @Value = DateTime.Now })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.messages, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter To Chat..." } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 chat-send">
                                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-control btn btn-info" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
```

[This is my actual page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51NqS.png)[when i send message it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OTov.png)

Comment: may be websockets would be better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't post the one thing we actually need: your controller action. But, my guess is that you're returning `View` there. You need to return `PartialView` instead. A partial view is only a partial view if it's used as a partial view.

Comment: yes i am using View i dont know how to use partialview

Comment: Simply replace `return View(someMode);` with `return PartialView(someModel);`